# Trouble updating date in database in MERN app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am working on my first MERN app and after resolving an issue with 404 errors trying to update the database it now appears my POST request is going through without errors- I got a status 200 for the request and "1 Document updated" message. I do not see a change to my database, though.  I'm wondering if my date format is ok?  Does anyone have any ideas for me to look into?  I'm not sure what to check next.
I'll include some code below.

A sample of my database:

```
{"_id":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"name":"Hoya",
"waterFrequency":{"$numberInt":"7"},
"waterDate":"2022-09-17"}
```

My route:

```
// This section will help you update a record by id.
plantRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("plant-babies-data");
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.id) };
  let newvalues = {
    $set: {
      waterDate: req.body.waterDate
    },
  };
  db_connect
    .collection("plants")
    .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
      response.json(res);
    });
});
```

From my front end component:

```
const [updatedPlant, setUpdatedPlant] = useState({
   waterDate: ""
 });

//set useState
  //calculate new waterDate
  let date = new Date();
  let freq = plant.waterFrequency;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + freq)
  setUpdatedPlant({waterDate:date}) 

// update database 
 async function submitData(id) {
   const editedDate = {
     waterDate: updatedPlant.waterDate
   };
    // This will send a post request to update the data in the database.
   await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/update/${id}`, {
     method: "POST",
     body: JSON.stringify(editedDate),
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
   });
 }
```

Comment: will the other values update as expected ? just to see if it's really an issue with `date` ..